# Sinónimo de "una especie de" refiriéndose a un tipo o a una descripción no a la definición biológica

Tags: sinónimos

En un texto científico asumo que no es apropiado tratar de describir algo como:

> X es una especie de resumen de los datos de entrada

No sé que sinónimo utilizar, quizá:

> X *puede ser visto* como un resumen de los datos de entrada

o

> X *puede ser descrito* como un resumen de los datos de entrada

¿Cómo se podría sustituir "es una especie de" para hacerlo más formal?

Comment: sin más contexto y sin saber exactamente porque X no es un resumen sino una especie de... es difícil.

Comment: Opino lo mismo que @Laura a mi me parece que con poner 'es un resumen' está correcto. Supongo que quieres explicar algo en algún trabajo en tu instituto o universidad, pero la verdad es que cuando algo X es una especie de resumen, tiende a ser un resumen. Por mi experiencia, a la gente no le gustan las especies de resumen, y normalmente acaban preguntándote lo mismo de siempre "una especie de?". Quizá deberías gastar más de una línea para explicar el concepto de "resumen sí, pero no". Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías decir:

> X es un tipo de resumen de los datos de entrada.
>   X es algo así como un resumen de los datos de entrada.
>   X es parecido a un resumen de los datos de entrada. (Personalmente no mi opción preferida.)

o simplemente:

> X es como un resumen de los datos de entrada.

Esta última forma puede tener el mismo sentido que le quieres dar a la frase pues no dice que efectivamente un resumen, sino algo similar.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. ¿Eres tú quién está escribiendo esa frase? En los textos científicos se tiene que tener clarísimo qué es "X". Qué mide, qué representa. Si ni siquiera tú lo tienes claro, imagínate la imagen que das al lector...

No hay sinónimos que puedan ayudarte en esa frase. De cualquiera de las tres maneras, estás mostrando que no tienes muy claro de lo que hablas, por lo que el lector dudará del propósito mismo de toda tu investigación. En el lenguaje científico caben pocos titubeos. El lenguaje científico prefiere las palabras cuanto más claras, sencillas y entendibles, mejor. Tratar de oscurecerlo o parecer "más erudito" siempre es contraproducente.

Si "X" es un resumen de los datos de entrada, dilo tranquilamente, pero con el detalle y concreción que el texto científico requiere. Por ejemplo: "X es la media aritmética de los voltajes recogidos por los sensores S1..SN".

Si lo que estás haciendo es dar tu interpretación o intentar describir el trabajo poco claro de otra persona y el significado de "X" tal y como tú lo entiendes, yo recomendaría algo como:

> - X se puede interpretar como un resumen de los datos de entrada.
> - X pretende mostrar un resumen de los datos de entrada.